# Issue with JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, json

Can you please take a look at following code and let me know why I am not able to run the program?

```
enter code here
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
  var comp=new Array("AAPL","MSFT","XRTX&");
  var t = setInterval(function(){getPrice();},200);});
  function getPrice() {
    for (var i=0;i<comp.length;i++){
    $.getJSON('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q='+comp[i]+'&callback=?', function(response){
  var stockInfo = response[0];
  var stockString = '<div id="stockprice">';
   stockString += 'Candente Copper: DNT $'+''+stockInfo.l+'';
   stockString += '</div>';
   $('#stockprice').replaceWith(stockString);
   $("#stockprice:contains('-')").addClass('red'); 
   $("#stockprice:contains('+')").addClass('green');
   }      
   });
   }​
```

Is there any problem with my Array object or other parts of program has issue? Please be advised that the code works fine without calling the array elements.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Hi Ralgha, here is the code. I edited the link

Comment: @Ralgha In my opinion, he should post the important parts of the code, and describe what he tried, but still linking to a jsfiddle! This is absolutely fine.

Comment: Can i ask why I got - for this question?

Comment: You're performing 3 Ajax requests every 200 milliseconds? 15 Ajax requests per second is way too much...

Comment: @  Šime ,Please forget that part I will fix it later

Comment: You should install Firebug and run this code again. That way we could be in much better position to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `{`s, `}`s, `(`s and `)`s do not all match up correctly. Also, in order for your function to have a reference to the `comp` variable, they must both be in the same function scope, in this case: `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`. You'll notice that I also increased your `setInterval` to `2000` (2s).

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PqXCV/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var comp = new Array("AAPL","MSFT","XRTX&");
   var t = setInterval(function(){getPrice();},2000);

    function getPrice() 
    {
       for (var i=0;i<comp.length;i++){
        $.getJSON('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q='+comp[i]+'&callback=?', function(response){
         var stockInfo = response[0];
         var stockString = '<div id="stockprice">';
         stockString += 'Candente Copper: DNT $'+''+stockInfo.l+'';
         stockString += '</div>';

         $('#stockprice').replaceWith(stockString);
         $("#stockprice:contains('-')").addClass('red');  
         $("#stockprice:contains('+')").addClass('green');
       });
      }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Chase I got the idea now, I wish there were morepeople like you here istead of vise people! who just can put Minues on questions!